# remove regions in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Ctrl M-L doesn't toggle all the regions in vb.net (2008) when there's a hierarchy between the regions. I don't like regions. Is there a way to expand ALL the regions or remove them permanently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's no such thing as expanding all outlining in nested outlines, Cntrl-M, L is the one to expand all outlining (or cntrl-m, cntrl-m to expand 1 region). VB.NET doesn't have an option to toggle outlining mode as C# has.

Answer (score 3):

In VB.Net, do a Search and Replace and select Use Hidden and Use Regex:

Replace:

```
^.*\#(end)*(:Wh)*region.*\n
```

With:

Answer (score 1):

There is a claim by James Nies that "NArrange could also be used as a tool to strip regions from source code."

> I hadn't thought about it until now,
>   but NArrange could also be used as a
>   tool to strip regions from source
>   code.
>
> If you were to define an empty
>   elements declaration for types, see
>   below, then NArrange will just parse
>   the members and write them back. It
>   won't sort anything, but rather will
>   just strip regions and clean up
>   whitespace between members.

```
 <Element Type="Type" Id="DefaultType">
     <Elements>
         <Element>
              <Elements />
         </Element>
     </Elements>
 </Element>
```

> However, this won't remove regions
>   that are defined within members.

Source: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/codegen/narrange.aspx?msg=2579903#xx2579903xx